# flash player installed but not working in firefox fedora21 x86_64

Tags: fedora, adobe-flash, plugin

I am using fedora 21 x86_64 workstation, Firefox and flash player are updated but in sometime not working.

For example, the game Pet Rescue Saga working fine but Papa Pear Saga not working, it tells me "No Flash Player found", as I know in Ubuntu, there is a plugin named Fresh plugin for Firefox and i got the same problem, but when I installed the Fresh plugin, the game worked fine.

So how to install the Fresh plugin or is there any similar plugins to it or any missed dependencies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some games don't have to work because official flash player is not developed any more. So new features can missing. But most probably site is just checking flash player version to force you to update.

Alternative is using pepper flash players from Google Chrome. This is what Fresh does. So just search for something like "firefox pepper". But from my own experience I know that it's does more problems than solves (freezes, crashes). My best advice would be use Chrome for tasks where old flash player can't be used.

And also you can install Fresh plugin from source. https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin. All packages you need are of course in Fedora too. Only with slightly different names, so use 'yum search' and 'yum provides' to install required dependency (both development and runtime). And of course you must install Google Chrome.